# При нажатии на кнопку отправит- ничего не происходит Java Python Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Есть древо комментариев и при нажатии на кнопку "Ответить" на комментарий ничего не происходит
я предполагаю, что это связанно с JavaScript и Ajax кодом
Как вы думаете, в чем проблема и как ее решить ?!

При добавлении комментариев через админку, всё работает

```html
<!-- base.html -->

{% load comments_tree %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.." integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{ comments|comments_filter }}
        <hr>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="{%url 'comment_create'%}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token%}
                {{ comment_form|crispy }}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Отправить">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap..." integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".reply".)on('click', function(){
            var parentId = $(this).attr('data-id')
            $("#form-"+parentId).fadeToggle();
        })
        $(".submit-reply").on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            var parentId = $(this).attr('data-submit-reply')
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id')
            var text = $("#form-'+id).find('textarea[name="comment-text"]').val();
            function getCookie(name) {
                let cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cookieValue;
            }
            const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
            data = {
                user: "{{ request.user.username }}",
                parentId: parentId,
                text: text,
                id: id,
                csrfmiddleweartoken: csrftoken
            }
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                data: data,
                url: "{% url 'comment_child_create' %}",
                success: function(data){
                    window.location.replace('/post-comments')
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>

</html>
```

```py
# comments_tree.py

from django.template import Library
from django.utils.html import mark_safe


register = Library()


@register.filter
def comments_filter(comments_list):
    res = """
    <ul> style="list-style-type:none;">
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-2">
            {}
        </div>
    </ul>
    """
    i = ''
    for comment in comments_list:
        i += """
        <li>
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-2 mt-2 p-0">
                <small>{author}</small> | опубликовано: {timestamp}
                <hr>
                <p>{text} | id={id}</p>
                
                <a href="#" class="reply" data-id="{id}" data-parent={parent_id}>Ответить</a>
                <form action"" method="POST" class="comment-form form-group" id"form-{id}" style="display:none;">
                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comment-text"></textarea><br>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-reply" data-id="{id}" data-submit-reply="{parent_id}" value="Отправить">
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
        """.format(id=comment['id'], author=comment['author'], timestamp=comment['timestamp'], text=comment['text'], parent_id=comment['parent_id'])
        if comment.get('children'):
            i += comments_filter(comment['children'])
    return mark_safe(res.format(i))
```

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation


class Post(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='Автор', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название поста')
    text = models.TextField()
    comments = GenericRelation('comment')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='Автор', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст комментария')
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        verbose_name='Родительский комментарий',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='comment_children',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата создания комметария')
    is_child = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
    
    @property
    def get_parent(self):
        if not self.parent:
            return ""
        return self.parent
```

```py
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import transaction
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import CommentForm
from .utils import create_comments_tree


def base_view(request):
    comments = Post.objects.first().comments.all()
    result = create_comments_tree(comments)
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'comments': result, 'comment_form': comment_form})


def create_comment(request):
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.user = request.user
        new_comment.text = comment_form.cleaned_data['text']
        new_comment.content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model='post')
        new_comment.objects_id = 1
        new_comment.parent = None
        new_comment.is_child = False
        new_comment.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/post-comments')


@transaction.atomic
def create_child_comment(request):
    user_name = request.POST.get('user')
    current_id = request.POST.get('id')
    text = request.POST.get('text')
    user = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(models='post')
    parent = Comment.objects.get(id=int(current_id))
    is_child = False if not parent else True
    Comment.objects.create(
        user=user, text=text, content_type=content_type, object_id=1,
        parent=parent, is_child=is_child
    )
    comments_ = Post.objects.first().comments.all()
    comments_list = create_comments_tree(comments_)
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'comments': comments_list})
```

Comment: На вопрос в том виде в котором Вы отправили его Вам врятли кто то ответил, так как он не читабелен. Вы же на питоне пишете, а не си, хотя бы отступы добавили бы

Comment: в фильтре `id"form-{id}"` , символ потеряли. а вообще с jquery проще в обработчике на кнопку `let form = $(this).closest('form);`, а данные из формы брать через `FormData`, точно не помню как, редко использовал

Comment: Добрый день Про какой именно символ идет речь ?

Comment: `id"form-{id}"` пропущен символ  `=`